# Euler characteristic of $n$ projective space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need to compute the Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{R}P^n$, but honestly I'm kinda lost.
Can anyone help me?

Edit:
My definition of Euler characteristic is $\mathcal{X}(X)=v-e+f$, where $v$ is vertex, $e$ is edges and $f$ is faces.
I kinda brute forced it (I tried a couple of examples) and to me it seems to follow the rule $\mathcal{X}(\mathbb{R}P^n)=1-n$ but I'm not completely sure about that since mine is not a formal proof.
To show that I used the idea that $\mathbb{R}P\#\mathbb{R}P$ is the same as the Klein Bottle. So every time I add two projective plane to the sum of $n$ projective space is like to sum a Klein Bottle. I honestly don't know of much that really makes sense, but to me it works.
Please consider that this is something I use to show a small passage in a much bigger exercise, so it's not very important for my exam, I just want to be prepared without without being too specific if my teacher asked me how I got that.

Comment: Which definition of Euler characteristic are you using? And please provide us with more information on what your thoughts are, where the problem is from etc.

Comment: @Con I added some more info

Comment: That definition of Euler characteristic is the special case for surfaces but $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is not a surface for $n\neq 2$. For general $n$ you have to apply [the proper Euler characteristic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition) which can be calculated from [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) for example or alternatively represent $\mathbb{R}P^n$ as a CW complex and calculate the number of cells in each dimension.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is not the same as the connected sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Which one are you interested in?